# How to send audit.log to remote server with syslog-ng

Tags: audit, syslog-ng

Good day,

I have SLES 10 with syslog-ng (syslog-ng-1.6.8-20.23.1)
and I cannot get the proper configuration so the file /var/log/audit/audit.log is sent to the remote syslog server.

I used tcpdump and I can see some details in the packets that are sent to the remote server, but  I am not seeing anything with the audit format in the tcp packet.

```
filter f_audit   { facility(13); };
filter f_audit2 {facility(security);};

destination d_local_facility {
  file("/var/log/$FACILITY/$FACILITY.log");


destination d_remote_loghost { tcp("$hostname" port(514)); };

log {
  source(s_local);
    destination(d_remote_loghost5);

};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to [configure a file source in syslog-ng](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-sources-file.html) that reads the /var/log/audit/audit.log file, and include this source in a log statement. I can't see that in your config file.

BTW, syslog-ng version 1.6 is ancient beyond words. syslog-ng 3.7 can [parse auditd logs to extract information](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/linux-audit-parser.html), so you might want to upgrade. You can find some SLES packages for syslog-ng at https://syslog-ng.org/3rd-party-binaries/

Comment: I'm just here b/c I'm learning this stuff too but I think this is the right answer http://edoceo.com/howto/syslog-ng

Answer (score 0):

In SLES 10, I finally used a script at boot.  The file after.local is the equivalent of rc.local

So, in /etc/init.d/after.local:

nohup /usr/bin/tailf /var/log/audit/audit.log | /bin/logger -t audispd  -p local6.info &

Its easier in SLES 11 because the auditspd dispatcher exists.